# Mission build three of any levels

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

To me that sounds like the same kind of level. Or can I do residential and retail and service etc?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you understood correctly. That simply means you are free to build any combination of 3 levels (but I've never built 3 of the same kind of levels for these kind of missions, so I'm not sure if that would fulfill the mission).

Comment: It would fulfill the mission to build three of the same.